# Create an empty pandas MultiIndex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a data frame in a function where I initially have only the indexing data. I am passing two lists (one is date one is some numbers they have different lenght) into my function that should be then turned into indexes in a pandas dataframe. Here is the code I am trying to run:

```
import pandas as pd
date_list = pd.date_range(pd.datetime.today(), periods=100).tolist()
my_randoms =[random.randrange(1,101,1) for _ in range (10)]
def create_multiindex_df(**idxs):
    idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(list(idxs.values()), names=idxs.keys())
    core_df = pd.DataFrame([],index=idx)
create_multiindex_df(randoms1=my_randoms,dates=date_list)
```

However I receive a cryptic error:

KeyError: 1

I would appreciate your help on this one!

Comment: Its working fine here. Also dont forget to add `return core_df` at the end of create_multindex function

Comment: What a loss of time! It was a different line of code, that was causing the error. Sorry and thanks! I needed the clean-up to get things straight.